# pattern.web URL dowload error -- IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, linux

I am having trouble using [the URL object](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web) from [the `web` package of the pattern library](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#URL). When I try to download text from a `URL` object, I get a permission error.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pattern.web
>>> urlObject=pattern.web.URL("http://google.com")
>>> urlResponse = urlObject.download()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/web/__init__.py", line 426, in download
    cache[id] = data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/web/cache/__init__.py", line 96, in __setitem__
    f = open(self._hash(k), "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/web/cache/tmp/c7b920f57e553df2bb68272f61570210'
```

I had no problem with this when running python with `sudo`, but I would like to understand what is going on here and how I can avoid granting root permissions to python just to download a URL. Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

Running Ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7.3, pattern version 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the owner/group of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/web/` to my user seems to have resolved the issue. I installed pattern via pip, nothing fancy, so I am assuming this is a bug and the permissions were too tight when pattern was installed.

Comment: That's a very crude workaround, though.  No user should have write access anywhere under `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Agreed. I have filed [an issue on the pattern github](https://github.com/clips/pattern/issues/105).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in a directory where you have write access because it is attempting to create a cache file.

(Probably want to clean up cache files from when you ran it with `sudo` because it seems to have polluted your system directories with chaff.)

It looks like you could try

```
urlResponse = urlObject.download(cached=False)
```

to disable the caching functionality.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think you're right and the issue is I don't have the correct permissions to mess with the `pattern` cache. I know I have write access in the directory I'm running from, since `touch test` and `python -c 'open("test.txt","w").write("hello world\n")'` both work. But when I run `pattern.web.cache.clear()` as non-root, I get the same error as above.The confusing part for me is I didn't do anything fancy to install pattern, so I don't understand how the permissions in /usr/local/lib could be incorrect.

Comment: As a regular user, you mustn't have write access to `/usr/local/lib`.  I have been assuming you are running the code out of `/usr/local/lib` and that it's simply writing to the current directory, as any sane code would.

Comment: Yes. That's what was so surprising to me--the implication is in order to use caching in pattern.web, your user needs write access to the pattern install dir under `/usr/local/lib`, which definitely seems to break convention.

I didn't try `cached=False` before I changed the permissions in the install directory, but I bet that would have worked.